# How can I read data updated to useState from a useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, get

I've seen similar questions to this, but none of them answer my question. For the code, it's this.

```js
  const [raceData, updateRaceData] = useState();
  const [raceChosen, updateRaceChosen] = useState();

  const url = "http://localhost:5000/races/viewraces";

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        const allRaces = response.data.races;
        updateRaceData(allRaces);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
  }, []);


  console.log(raceData[0]);
```

So when I console.log() raceData and raceData[0] or raceData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkKl.png), it works and doesn't give me any trouble. But if I instead do
console.log(raceData[0].race), and then refresh, it starts telling me :

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'race')

Any help on figuring out why trying to access things from the response I'm getting doesn't fully work would be appreciated.

***Edit:***
Here is the object response with raceData[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkKl.png)]:
[Response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkKl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mapping over the racedata as such:

`raceData?.map((race) => console.log(race))`

this should populate your raceData info

Comment: So in truth, this isn't what I wanted to do, but it did make me realize what I was doing wrong, so thank you for the memory jarring.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is running console.log(raceData[0]) before the variable being assigned. Try `raceData && console.log(raceData[0]);` which will only execute the `console.log()` if raceData is assigned.